# How do I fix my docker-compose.yml file that is unable to load schema from 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/

Tags: python-3.x, docker, github, docker-compose, github-api

I am fairly new to docker. I use the latest versions of Python, Django, and Docker. I have been working on this project for two weeks now, I already created the `docker-compose.yml` file and have built my docker image since. Everything worked well and swimmingly before but today I tried to run `docker-compose up` and then I was hit hit with this issue:

`Unable to load schema from 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/master/schema/compose-spec.json': Request vscode/content failed unexpectedly without providing any details.`

This is what my `docker-compose.yml` file looks like:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:15
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=2030
      - POSTGRES_DB=ikengaBK
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U postgres" ]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
```

I have checked the GitHub connection to the VSCode app and that checks out. I don't know what else could be the issue. Can someone help me sense of this issue?

For further context, I only started noticing this issue tonight, other days the docker-compose file has worked well and fine.

Comment: Is this the full ```docker-compose.yml``` ?
because I just added 
```volumes:
   postgres-data: ```
and did work perfectly fine

Comment: No it's not. In the full one postgres is included